# Python: Extract only numbers in the format of 00-00-00 from a string

Tags: python

I have a string like so: `Test Step 01-08-04 U upper 100 m/s`

And currently I use:

```
self.current_xtp_test_case = re.findall("\d+", test_case.attrib["name"])
self.current_xtp_test_case = ''.join(map(str,self.current_xtp_test_case[-1:]))
self.current_xtp_test_case = self.current_xtp_test_case.lstrip("0")
```

The above is supposed to get the last number in the 00-00-00 pattern, which should end up being `4` as I need to remove the `0`. But now with the data I am processing, sometimes there might be a number other than the `00-00-00` as with the example above, I have 100 in the string at the end which messes up the logic of my current code.

How can I change my code so that I can only select the last number in the pattern 01-03-04 - I only want to ever select the `04` part. Hopefully this makes sense?

Comment: Why not  reg = '-([0-9]+)'  and then for each line print(rexp.findall(t)[-1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood from the question looks like this is what you are asking

```html
import re

string_to_parse = "Test Step 01-08-04 U upper 100 m/s"
find_result = re.findall('\d+-\d+-\d+', my_string)[0]
print(find_result[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
s = ['Test Step 00-00-00 U upper 0 m/s',
     'Test Step 00-00-09 U upper 100 m/s',
     'Test Step 01-08-04 U upper 150 m/s']
[re.findall('[0-9]{2,}\-[0-9]{2,}\-([0-9]{2,})',x)[0] for x in s]
```

**output:**

```
['00', '09', '04']
```

Hope that help ;)